# IPMI reports high values tempreture values of VRD1 and VRD2

Tags: ipmi

I have a supermicro U2 server and its sensors report high temperature for VRD1 and VRD2 of 261 F, and next to it, it reports "Upper Non-recoverable". I googled this and I couldn't find any information about these parameters (VRD1 and VRD2).

First, what is VRD1 and VRD2? And what do they measure?

If these values are high, what can I do about it?

What does "Upper Non-recoverable" mean?

I appreciate any help,

Comment: Could you elaborate further? When this happens - on boot or some time after? Does machine power cycle fixes it? Is your memory on Supermicro's tested memory list? What server model, what MB?

Comment: @grs, thanks for the quick reply. This happens all the time. Initially I didn't think much of it but after 6 months of running the server in the data center, I started paying attention to it; andf now I am very worried. I don't have access to that information right now, but I believe the MB is supermicro, and with regards to the memory I have to assume that is the case. I bought the U2 Server from ServersDirect.com. It is very similar to this one, but not exactly http://www.serversdirect.com/config.asp?config_id=SDR-S2500-T08

Answer (score 1):

To begin, thermal sensor values are normally reported in Celsius, not Fahrenheit, so you seem to have something converting the values for you. 261 F is 127 C. This also happens to be the maximum value of an 8-bit signed integer.

Normally, sensor values reported as 127 (or as -128, the minimum value of an 8-bit signed integer) refer to sensors which do not actually exist in the hardware, or sometimes sensors which exist but are not functioning.

Indeed, some [firmware release notes](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wikiDE/images/7/72/IPMI_Firmware_Release_Note_2.44.txt) found on the Internet indicate that these VRD1 and VRD2 sensors were removed in a firmware update, which strongly suggests they never existed. Try updating your IPMI firmware. Or you can just ignore them.

Comment: +1 for the link and the suggestion to update the firmware. But I disagree with just ignoring the sensors, unless the update take care of them. One of my Supermicro servers reports such high temperatures (using IPMIview got them both in C and F). In my case it is memory related, thus I won't "just" ignore the sensor readings. Point being false sensor information may be sign of trouble.

Comment: Not when the sensors don't actually exist.

Comment: @Michae & Grs, I appreciate the input. I have upgradef the firmware to version 2.5 from supermicro's website and it seems the old way the censor was being calculated was wrong and it was reporting these outrageous numbers. So in a way, both of you are correct. BTW, these values were not removed; they are there irrespective of the release notes. The interesting thing, via the web interface, the Java Console would not work, but via the IMPIView it is working. If I have to guess this is related to the new firmware and for another question!! Man thanks guys.